# How to convert normal date to julian date in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Suppose my date  is localtimestamp datatype and I need to convert it into Julian date||HHMM   in informatica

Where Julian date is JJJ
HHMM is hours and minutes

For example today is 29-10- 2021 Julian date is 302,output should come with concat of JJJHHMM

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for modified julian date which is just a number. If you are looking for modified julian date, then use -

```
TO_CHAR(DATE_COL, 'J')|| TO_CHAR(DATE_COL, 'HHMM')
```

If you are looking for normal Julian date (format is yyyyddd) then use

```
TO_CHAR(DATE_COL, 'YYYYDDD')|| TO_CHAR(DATE_COL, 'HHMM')
```